# Screen Record my browser

Tags: video, recording

I need to record just my browser and nothing else on the desktop. Does anyone know how I can do that?  I know I can do a screen recording with QuickTime, but it takes the entire desktop.

I want to stick a demo of something into a presentation, therefore just want the browser visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jing Basic](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/) is free and excellent.

Comment: free to capture swf only, with watermark

Answer (score 4):

Quicktime 10 (Lion) now allows you to record an area of your screen, not just the entire screen. Select "File → New Screen Recording," click the red "record" button, and Quicktime will tell you:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) is an excellent screencasting tool. It always records the whole desktop, but you can use its Crop Canvas tool after the recording is done to crop to just the browser screen.

Answer (score 2):

I used Snapz Pro X for a long time (now on OS X 10.6.6). It allows you to select the size of the screen you want to capture before you start capturing. I like the software and more importantly the support (once I misplaced the serial number after upgrading OS).

In my opinion, worth every penny. 
Link: http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/

Hope this helps.

Please mark your question as answered if this helps, thanks.

Comment: Snapz Pro X has been my go-to program for still screen captures since dinosaurs ruled the Earth; it's great for that. It's not optimal for recording video of the screen, however. It requires a very lengthy rendering step after the capture is done. I found that long wait really hinders my workflow, which is why I switched to Screenflow for video recording. Screenflow also has extensive editing capabilities to polish the recording.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did the screen recording in quicktime and edited it in imovie. This had a cost of 0 which was pretty important for me as this isn't something I'd of typically done.